# Using loops to limit memory usage

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I'm running an R script on a cluster passing through many files (2Ok+ files, 100GB of data). I am trying to optimize my code for memory usage because my scripts often hit the step memory limit (despite raising the limits).

Currently, I avoid using functions that take the whole dataframe in one go and prefer to use a loop. My reasoning is sure loops may be less efficient in terms of computing time but I don't care about computing time, I care about not hitting the memory limit and loops seem to solve that. I was looking for confirmation that using loops instead of a function may be better in terms of memory. Or does it just happen that I'm getting rid of inefficient functions and the loops have nothing to do with it ?

Thanks!

I tried using loops instead of functions. I'm no longer hitting step memory limits. I want to check it is indeed due to the loops.

Comment: If you're dealing with text files package {vroom} might be an option as it lazily loads the data: https://vroom.r-lib.org/index.html